# How to Manualy install the bootloader in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, boot

I have a small notebook that i was using a previous version of ubuntu on and it worked perfectly until i did a clean install with the latest 12.10.  I install ubuntu by usb since the notebook has no cd drive.  I am not duelbooting, only ubuntu is on this notebook.

Everything seems to be installing perfectly until i get an error when it tries to install the bootloader.  I did a little google searching and saw it was common so i decided to proceed without the bootloader and install in manualy later.  However when i tried to install it later from the codes that i found online using the terminal, i get no luck.

I am only a newbe to linux and the terminal even tho i have used ubuntu for a while, it has mostly been used for travel and leasure. ie:internet and films

If anyone can help it be most appreciated as i am not sure what i am doing wrong.  What i have tried so far is installing the bootloader by booting into the live usb and using the terminal there, but to be honest i am unsure what i am doing.

Thanks

K.

Comment: What is the error? What commands have you used? Be specific

Answer (score 0):

You can boot your netbook with SuperGrubDisk from a USB-Stick. When your Ubuntu is booted, open a terminal and type:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

The first command updates the bootloader settings, the second one installs it to the first hard drive (or ssd or whatever).